# Select on change not passing value

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get a function to count the number of times a number appears in an array based on a selection from a dropdown.

If I do it direct with `favouriteCar(3);` I get a value of 2 in the console.

However if I select from the drop down, nothing happens.

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car to see how many people like it:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars" onchange="favouriteCar(this.value);">
    <option value="0">Please select a car...</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">VW</option>
    <option value="3">BMW</option>
    <option value="4">MG</option>
    <option value="5">Suzuki</option>
</select>

<script>
    const carlikes = [2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1];

    function favouriteCar(value) {

        var count = 0;

        carlikes.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
        
        return count;

        console.log(count); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `return` will stop further execution of your function. Move the `console.log()` above the line with the `return` if you want to see a log in the console

Comment: `favouriteCar(parseInt(this.value));` you are passing `this.value` that will be a string and you are using that value as a number in your function. But obviously you are also returning before console.log.. but that's just a typo I suppose

Comment: Also, why not filter instead of loop counting? `carlikes.filter(v => v === value).length`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting NaN when entering a number in an input field and combining it with Math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203224/why-am-i-getting-nan-when-entering-a-number-in-an-input-field-and-combining-it-w)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get familiar with the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method to listen to events. It's much more predictable and allows you to separate your HTML and JavaScript. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

That being said, the `value` of the select will **always** be represented as a string. Therefor you must first convert it to a number before  using it in your loop.

There is little point to  use `return` here as you can't use the result of your event listener, so omit it. The `return` statement causes the function to end at that position, so everything after `return` won't be reached.

```js
const carlikes = [2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1];
const select = document.querySelector('#cars');

function favouriteCar(event) {
  const value = Number(event.target.value);
  var count = 0;
  carlikes.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
  console.log(count);
}

select.addEventListener('change', favouriteCar);
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car to see how many people like it:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="0">Please select a car...</option>
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3">BMW</option>
  <option value="4">MG</option>
  <option value="5">Suzuki</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get that count using `Array.filter` and then taking that `length`

```
function favouriteCar(value) {
    const count = carlikes.filter((e) => e === value).length;
    console.log(count);
}
```

```js
const carlikes = [2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1];
const select = document.querySelector('#cars');

function favouriteCar(event) {
  const value = Number(event.target.value);
    const count = carlikes.filter((e) => e === value).length;
    console.log(count);
}

select.addEventListener('change', favouriteCar);
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car to see how many people like it:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="0">Please select a car...</option>
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">VW</option>
  <option value="3">BMW</option>
  <option value="4">MG</option>
  <option value="5">Suzuki</option>
</select>
```